# Google Analytics embed examples doesn't work

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm trying to get started with google analytics API, and it's super frustrating. I have spent hours attempting to make their sample code work, and I'm at a loss for why it won't work.

here's my demo page html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>

        <script>
    (function(w,d,s,g,js,fs){
      g=w.gapi||(w.gapi={});g.analytics={q:[],ready:function(f){this.q.push(f);}};
      js=d.createElement(s);fs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      js.src='https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js';
      fs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fs);js.onload=function(){g.load('analytics');};
    }(window,document,'script'));
    </script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.2/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.2/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/public/javascript/embed-api/components/view-selector2.js"></script>
    <script src="/public/javascript/embed-api/components/date-range-selector.js"></script>
    <script src="/public/javascript/embed-api/components/active-users.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/css/chartjs-visualizations.css">


    <script>
    gapi.analytics.ready(function() {

      gapi.analytics.auth.authorize({
        container: 'embed-api-auth-container',
        clientid: '1049955524348-656m95v1jedr07guiunt7e6h7quv1esl.apps.googleusercontent.com'
      });

      var activeUsers = new gapi.analytics.ext.ActiveUsers({
        container: 'active-users-container',
        pollingInterval: 5
      });

      activeUsers.once('success', function() {
        var element = this.container.firstChild;
        var timeout;

        this.on('change', function(data) {
          var element = this.container.firstChild;
          var animationClass = data.delta > 0 ? 'is-increasing' : 'is-decreasing';
          element.className += (' ' + animationClass);

          clearTimeout(timeout);
          timeout = setTimeout(function() {
            element.className =
                element.className.replace(/ is-(increasing|decreasing)/g, '');
          }, 3000);
        });
      });

      var viewSelector = new gapi.analytics.ext.ViewSelector2({
        container: 'view-selector-container',
      })
      .execute();

      viewSelector.on('viewChange', function(data) {
        var title = document.getElementById('view-name');
        title.textContent = data.property.name + ' (' + data.view.name + ')';

        activeUsers.set(data).execute();

        renderWeekOverWeekChart(data.ids);
        renderYearOverYearChart(data.ids);
        renderTopBrowsersChart(data.ids);
        renderTopCountriesChart(data.ids);
      });

      function renderWeekOverWeekChart(ids) {
        var now = moment(); 

        var thisWeek = query({
          'ids': ids,
          'dimensions': 'ga:date,ga:nthDay',
          'metrics': 'ga:sessions',
          'start-date': moment(now).subtract(1, 'day').day(0).format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
          'end-date': moment(now).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
        });

        var lastWeek = query({
          'ids': ids,
          'dimensions': 'ga:date,ga:nthDay',
          'metrics': 'ga:sessions',
          'start-date': moment(now).subtract(1, 'day').day(0).subtract(1, 'week')
              .format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
          'end-date': moment(now).subtract(1, 'day').day(6).subtract(1, 'week')
              .format('YYYY-MM-DD')
        });

        Promise.all([thisWeek, lastWeek]).then(function(results) {

          var data1 = results[0].rows.map(function(row) { return +row[2]; });
          var data2 = results[1].rows.map(function(row) { return +row[2]; });
          var labels = results[1].rows.map(function(row) { return +row[0]; });

          labels = labels.map(function(label) {
            return moment(label, 'YYYYMMDD').format('ddd');
          });

          var data = {
            labels : labels,
            datasets : [
              {
                label: 'Last Week',
                fillColor : 'rgba(220,220,220,0.5)',
                strokeColor : 'rgba(220,220,220,1)',
                pointColor : 'rgba(220,220,220,1)',
                pointStrokeColor : '#fff',
                data : data2
              },
              {
                label: 'This Week',
                fillColor : 'rgba(151,187,205,0.5)',
                strokeColor : 'rgba(151,187,205,1)',
                pointColor : 'rgba(151,187,205,1)',
                pointStrokeColor : '#fff',
                data : data1
              }
            ]
          };

          new Chart(makeCanvas('chart-1-container')).Line(data);
          generateLegend('legend-1-container', data.datasets);
        });
      }

      function renderYearOverYearChart(ids) {
        var now = moment(); 

        var thisYear = query({
          'ids': ids,
          'dimensions': 'ga:month,ga:nthMonth',
          'metrics': 'ga:users',
          'start-date': moment(now).date(1).month(0).format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
          'end-date': moment(now).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
        });

        var lastYear = query({
          'ids': ids,
          'dimensions': 'ga:month,ga:nthMonth',
          'metrics': 'ga:users',
          'start-date': moment(now).subtract(1, 'year').date(1).month(0)
              .format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
          'end-date': moment(now).date(1).month(0).subtract(1, 'day')
              .format('YYYY-MM-DD')
        });

        Promise.all([thisYear, lastYear]).then(function(results) {
          var data1 = results[0].rows.map(function(row) { return +row[2]; });
          var data2 = results[1].rows.map(function(row) { return +row[2]; });
          var labels = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun',
                        'Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'];

          for (var i = 0, len = labels.length; i < len; i++) {
            if (data1[i] === undefined) data1[i] = null;
            if (data2[i] === undefined) data2[i] = null;
          }

          var data = {
            labels : labels,
            datasets : [
              {
                label: 'Last Year',
                fillColor : 'rgba(220,220,220,0.5)',
                strokeColor : 'rgba(220,220,220,1)',
                data : data2
              },
              {
                label: 'This Year',
                fillColor : 'rgba(151,187,205,0.5)',
                strokeColor : 'rgba(151,187,205,1)',
                data : data1
              }
            ]
          };

          new Chart(makeCanvas('chart-2-container')).Bar(data);
          generateLegend('legend-2-container', data.datasets);
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
          console.error(err.stack);
        });
      }

      function renderTopBrowsersChart(ids) {

        query({
          'ids': ids,
          'dimensions': 'ga:browser',
          'metrics': 'ga:pageviews',
          'sort': '-ga:pageviews',
          'max-results': 5
        })
        .then(function(response) {

          var data = [];
          var colors = ['#4D5360','#949FB1','#D4CCC5','#E2EAE9','#F7464A'];

          response.rows.forEach(function(row, i) {
            data.push({ value: +row[1], color: colors[i], label: row[0] });
          });

          new Chart(makeCanvas('chart-3-container')).Doughnut(data);
          generateLegend('legend-3-container', data);
        });
      }

      function renderTopCountriesChart(ids) {
        query({
          'ids': ids,
          'dimensions': 'ga:country',
          'metrics': 'ga:sessions',
          'sort': '-ga:sessions',
          'max-results': 5
        })
        .then(function(response) {

          var data = [];
          var colors = ['#4D5360','#949FB1','#D4CCC5','#E2EAE9','#F7464A'];

          response.rows.forEach(function(row, i) {
            data.push({
              label: row[0],
              value: +row[1],
              color: colors[i]
            });
          });

          new Chart(makeCanvas('chart-4-container')).Doughnut(data);
          generateLegend('legend-4-container', data);
        });
      }

      function query(params) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
          var data = new gapi.analytics.report.Data({query: params});
          data.once('success', function(response) { resolve(response); })
              .once('error', function(response) { reject(response); })
              .execute();
        });
      }

      function makeCanvas(id) {
        var container = document.getElementById(id);
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        container.innerHTML = '';
        canvas.width = container.offsetWidth;
        canvas.height = container.offsetHeight;
        container.appendChild(canvas);

        return ctx;
      }

      function generateLegend(id, items) {
        var legend = document.getElementById(id);
        legend.innerHTML = items.map(function(item) {
          var color = item.color || item.fillColor;
          var label = item.label;
          return '<li><i style="background:' + color + '"></i>' +
              escapeHtml(label) + '</li>';
        }).join('');
      }

      Chart.defaults.global.animationSteps = 60;
      Chart.defaults.global.animationEasing = 'easeInOutQuart';
      Chart.defaults.global.responsive = true;
      Chart.defaults.global.maintainAspectRatio = false;

      function escapeHtml(str) {
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(str));
        return div.innerHTML;
      }

    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <header>
      <div id="embed-api-auth-container"></div>
      <div id="view-selector-container"></div>
      <div id="view-name"></div>
      <div id="active-users-container"></div>
    </header>
    <div class="Chartjs">
      <h3>This Week vs Last Week (by sessions)</h3>
      <figure class="Chartjs-figure" id="chart-1-container"></figure>
      <ol class="Chartjs-legend" id="legend-1-container"></ol>
    </div>
    <div class="Chartjs">
      <h3>This Year vs Last Year (by users)</h3>
      <figure class="Chartjs-figure" id="chart-2-container"></figure>
      <ol class="Chartjs-legend" id="legend-2-container"></ol>
    </div>
    <div class="Chartjs">
      <h3>Top Browsers (by pageview)</h3>
      <figure class="Chartjs-figure" id="chart-3-container"></figure>
      <ol class="Chartjs-legend" id="legend-3-container"></ol>
    </div>
    <div class="Chartjs">
      <h3>Top Countries (by sessions)</h3>
      <figure class="Chartjs-figure" id="chart-4-container"></figure>
      <ol class="Chartjs-legend" id="legend-4-container"></ol>
    </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

When the page loads, no charts or graphs appear and several errors show up in the console log.

> unreachable code after return statement[Learn More] 
>   moment.min.js:6:12384
>
> SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'[Learn More] 
>   view-selector2.js:1
>
> SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'[Learn More] 
>   date-range-selector.js:1
>
> SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'[Learn More] 
>   active-users.js:1
>
> TypeError: gapi.analytics.ext is undefined[Learn More] 
>   index3.html:57:7

I'm not sure where to go from here. Seems like the gap.analytics.ext undefined error is a biggie, but not sure why it would be undefined.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Non-Working page example can be seen here. 
https://beelocal.mobi/dev/nick/dashboard/index3.html